# Left join returns zero rows

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables:

```
question
question_id | question

question_answer
answer_id | question_id | choice_id | user_id | explain
```

I want to get all questions for which particular user haven't answered yet.

```
SELECT question, question_id as questionId 
FROM question q 
LEFT JOIN question_answer qa USING(question_id)
WHERE qa.user_id!=$userId
```

I get in this case zero rows. I tried also

```
SELECT question, q.question_id as questionId 
FROM question q 
LEFT JOIN question_answer qa ON q.question_id=qa.question_id AND qa.user_id!=$userId
```

Obviously this returns all records. I stuck here how to make this query.

Comment: You should have an extra `JOIN` with the users table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of your `LEFT JOIN` where you check for a specific user should be reversed, i.e. `user_id = $userId` instead of `user_id <> $userId`.

From the resulting rows you select the ones where `user_id IS NULL` to find the questions for which `$userId` has not answered (yet).

```
SELECT question, q.question_id as questionId 
FROM question q 
LEFT JOIN question_answer qa ON q.question_id=qa.question_id AND qa.user_id=$userId
WHERE qa.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not bound to use `JOIN` operation then you can try this as you

> want to get all questions for which particular user haven't answered
>   yet:

```
select * from question
where
    question_id not in (select distinct question_id from question_answer where user_id=$userId);
```

[**See the demo on Sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86cc4/1/0)

Don't know whether `not in` is slower or faster than `JOIN` operation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT question, q.question_id as questionId 
FROM question q 
LEFT JOIN question_answer qa ON q.question_id = qa.question_id 
WHERE qa.user_id IS NULL;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/958f1/1)

This will give you ***questions with no answers*** yet.

However, if you want to get users that have not answered questions yet, you should have an extra `JOIN` to the users table. Something like:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM  users u 
LEFT JOIN question_answer qa ON qa.user_id = u.id
WHERE qa.question_id IS NULL;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d464/10)

Answer (score 1):

i would modify the answer from MG above to be simply

```
SELECT question, q.question_id as questionId 
FROM question q 
LEFT JOIN question_answer qa ON q.question_id = qa.question_id 
and qa.user_id=2
WHERE qa.user_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Which is basically my answer :)

Comment: oh i'm sorry. when i tweaked his sqlfiddle with my above it seemed to generate the results u want

Comment: so if you go here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/958f1/5  you will see that you were looking for a particular user and his non answered questions